# Keep a predefined columns flow in the layout from mobile to desktop in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I'm trying to make a relatively simple 2 columns layout in bootstrap 3, but I need to keep an exact flow of the boxes when the page is viewed in desktop and in mobile.

Here are two images that describe what I'm trying to achieve:
Boxes with the same colour must be always close together, and the number I've put inside specify their flow, therefore their "row number" in the mobile view.

Desktop View:

[image: Desktop View]

Mobile View:

[image: Mobile View]

Here is my test on bootply, but I'm not able to keep the flow that I want, specially for box Red2:
https://www.bootply.com/uiBnf0XxxJ

Comment: You cannot do this with your current html structure. for `1,1,2` to be one after the other on mobile, they need to be in the same row or for example `1,1` in same row , `2` first in the next row etc. In your example, `3,4,4` are before `2` and in a different row.  You seem to need a masonry effect on your 'boxes' , so i suggest you look into javascript related solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with your current layout.

If you didn't want to change the layout you currently have, duplicating 2 into the first row and using hidden-sm and visible-sm would still work.

You also currently have 2,5 and 6 which aren't in a row which is incorrect according to the documentation as cols can only be children of rows.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 red"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 red"><h1>1</h1></div>

    <!-- Duplicated block -->
    <div class="col-md-6 red visible-sm"><br><br><br><br><h1>2</h1><br><br><br><br></div>

    <!--if I put the blue boxes here, then I'm not able to have Red2 just below Red1 in mobile layout-->
    <div class="col-md-12 blue"><br><br><br><br><h1>3</h1><br><br><br><br></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 blue"><h1>4</h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 blue"><h1>4</h1></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 red hidden-sm"><br><br><br><br><h1>2</h1><br><br><br><br></div>

    <div class="col-md-6 yellow"><h1>5</h1></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 yellow"><h1>6</h1></div>
</div>

 </div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 yellow">
  <br><br><h1>7</h1><br><br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't like to duplicate contents, maybe with js I could move Red2 box, instead of duplicating it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, if you create two container one for desktop and one for mobile I've create two container `div` with class of `.desktop-view` and `.mobile-view` and add `css media queries`

```css
  h1{
    width:100%;text-align:center;
  }
  .red {
    border:2px solid red;
  }
  .blue { 
    border:2px solid blue;
  }
  .yellow { 
    border:2px solid yellow;
  }
  .mobile-view { 
    display: none; 
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .mobile-view { 
      display: block; 
    }
    .desktop-view { 
      display: none; 
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container desktop-view">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 red"><h1>1</h1></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 red"><h1>1</h1></div>
        <!--if I put the blue boxes here, then I'm not able to have Red2 just below Red1 in mobile layout-->
        <div class="col-md-12 blue"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><h1>3</h1><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 blue"><h1>4</h1></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 blue"><h1>4</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 red">
          <br><br><br><br><br><h1>2</h1><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 yellow"><h1>5</h1></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 yellow"><h1>5</h1></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 yellow">
          <br><br><h1>6</h1><br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 yellow">
        <br><br><h1>7</h1><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container mobile-view">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-md-6 col-sm-6  red"><h1>1</h1></div>
      <div class=" col-md-6 col-sm-6  red"><h1>1</h1></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 red"><br><br><br><br><h1>2</h1><br><br><br><br></div>
      <!--if I put the blue boxes here, then I'm not able to have Red2 just below Red1 in mobile layout-->
      <div class="col-md-12 blue"><br><br><br><br><h1>3</h1><br><br><br><br></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 blue"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 blue"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 yellow"><h1>5</h1></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 yellow"><h1>5</h1></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 yellow"><h1>6</h1></div>
      <div class="col-md-12 yellow">
        <br><br><h1>7</h1><br><br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but I should duplicate the contents... and some of them are js charts, so a little bit dirty to do it